# qtpy only showing white screen even if i run simple code

Tags: python, qtpy

This isnt my main program but even this results in blank white screen

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])

window = QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle('My Browser')

view = QWebEngineView()
window.setCentralWidget(view)

view.setUrl(QUrl('https://www.google.com'))

window.show()

app.exec_()
```